# Is it possible to create a check box to record a user's input without resorting to Shiny in R?

Tags: r, input

Is it possible to create a tick-box to record an user's input without using Shiny?

For example

- A program is launched
- A window with boxes to tick is open
- The user ticks one of the boxes
- The input is sent to a variable

Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: What do you do? Html-report via Rmarkdown?

Answer (score 1):

its done with the runGadget ability that miniUI adds to shiny
i.e. make a lightweight shiny app that can pop up in a dialog window and the values get returned to the calling environment. example for you .

```
library(miniUI)
library(shiny)

checker <- function() {
  ui <- miniPage(
    gadgetTitleBar(paste("Tick Boxes")),
    miniButtonBlock(
      checkboxInput(inputId = "check_1",
                    label = "check 1 ?"),
      checkboxInput(inputId = "check_2",
                    label = "check 2 ?")
    )
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output) {
    

    
    observeEvent(input$done, {
      stopApp(list(
        c1 = input$check_1,
        c2 = input$check_2
      ))
    })
    observeEvent(input$cancel, {
      stopApp(NULL)
    })
    
  }
  
  runGadget(ui, server,viewer = dialogViewer("my diag"))
}

checker()
```