# R View gt table in window from script message box three buttons

Tags: r, gt

**Ultimate goal:**  Display gt table in pop-out window with 3 buttons to control script action

**Minimum goal:**  Display a gt table in pop-out viewer window

**Full detail:**
I am creating a table using the `gt` package in R.  I want to display the table with three options for how to proceed:  OK (script continues), Edit (allow the user to make minor modifications to a specific column), Cancel (something has gone wrong and the process needs to be terminated).  My plan is to allow a quick QC of the data before it gets saved.  My issue is that I have no idea how to display a gt table in a viewer window or with `tk_messageBox` and that's about the only package I know of that might do this.

Any ideas?

Here's an example `gt` table:

```
table <- gt(mtcars) %>% 
  tab_header(
    title = md("**2014 - 2019 Salary and Playoff Appearances**&#x26BD;"), 
    subtitle = "I am a boss")
```

Answer (score 0):

you could achieve such an effect with shiny/miniUI specifically runGadget()
see this answer I gave yesterday which is an example where the user is shown two checkboxes to interact with that are returned as data into the calling environment

[Is it possible to create a check box to record a user's input without resorting to Shiny in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73487795/is-it-possible-to-create-a-check-box-to-record-a-users-input-without-resorting/73488492#73488492)